# Why does IEnumerable.Any return True for a collection of False-booleans?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I recently needed to check two lists to see if the type of data matched the expected type, at the expected index. So I did a check on each element x at each index i and stored this comparison as a boolean, I then called Any to see if any of the booleans where true. However, the following statement always throws the exception.

```
var values = new object[] {(UInt64) 40, (Boolean) true, (Double) 45.3};
var types = new[] {typeof (UInt64), typeof (Boolean), typeof (Double)};

if (types.Select((x, i) => values[i].GetType() != x).Any())
    throw new Exception();
```

(I know why, but after spending a few minutes debugging I thought it would make a good question).

Comment: Remove the last sentence and just add your own answer ;) You can even do that in the process of asking the question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Any()` doesn't do what you think it does. Without a lambda expression in `Any()`, it will just check if there is **any** element in the enumerable it is called on.

You either want:

```
types.Select((x, i) => values[i].GetType() != x).Any(x => x)
```

or maybe

```
types.Where((x, i) => values[i].GetType() != x).Any()
```

Comment: I hadn't realized the indexer was available on `Where` and `Any` too.

Comment: @MeirionHughes To be honest I am not entirely sure about that, so I also added an example closer to your code. Let me check if my other examples would actually work.

Comment: @MeirionHughes Checked it: indexer is available in `Where`, but not in `Any`, so I removed the last example.

Comment: No, only  `Select`, `Where` and `SkipWhile` have an overload that projects the index.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Just checked that and removed the example that gave a compile error.

Answer (score 8):

[`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb337697(v=vs.100).aspx) without argument just checks if the sequence contains elements. If you want to know if there are any `true`s you have to use the [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
bool anyTrue = bools.Any(b => b);
```

Answer (score 7):

`Any` doesn't check what's in your sequence. It looks for **if** there is *Any* element in the sequence.So whether you have a sequence of true values of false doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx) of the Any() method.  The overload you are using just returns true if the sequence contains *stuff*, it doesn't care what the values are.  To check the booleans and only return if one them is true, your code would need to be

```
if (types.Select((x, i) => values[i].GetType() != x).Any(x => x))
    throw new Exception();
```